# Pygame (basics)

Tags: python, pygame

I have rectangle:

```
rect = pygame.Rect(10, 20, 100, 200)
```

and image:

```
img = pygame.image.load('ace_of_hearts.jpg')
```

How can I change a bigger (or smaller) image to fit a rectangle (with initial ratio of an image)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def resizeInto(surface, rect):
    surSize = list(surface.get_size())
    rectSize = rect.size
    for i in (0, 1):
        if surSize[i] > rectSize[i]:
            surSize[1 - i] = 1. * surSize[1 - i] / surSize[i] * rectSize[i]
            surSize[i] = rectSize[i]

    if surSize != surface.get_size():
        rounded = [int(round(s)) for s in surSize]
        surface = pygame.transform.smoothscale(surface, rounded)
    return surface
```

Comment: I wanted a simple solution, but no luck. Your example works great, I only change Pt.smoothscale(surface, rounded) to pygame.transform.smoothscale(surface, rounded). Thanks a lot for your attention, I will use this piece.

Comment: Great. Yeah I'll change it to `pygame.transform`, sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
rect = pygame.Rect(10, 20, 100, 200)
img = pygame.image.load('ace_of_hearts.jpg')
img = pygame.transform.scale(img, rect.size)
# rect.size returns (100, 200)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works, BUT a ratio of height and weight of an image is changing, how this problem could be solved without long calculations (to measure height and weight of an image, then of a rectangle, to find ratio of image and rectangle and so on...)?